# How to run welcome page from the <welcome-file-list>?

Tags: jsf

I am developing a project using `jsf` and `Primefaces`.

In that,I moved all my pages in to WEB-INF folder including my `welcomePage.xhtml` for prevent pages from the direct access in `URL`.

I was set that `welcomePage.xhtml` as `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml`:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcomePage.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

while running my application occured an error `HTTP Status 404`.

I do not know why its does not work.but its work when the `welcomePage.xhml` is in outside of the `WEB-INF`.

Any idea?

Comment: How should your web server find the file in an arbitrary sub folder? Try `<welcome-file>WEB-INF/welcomePage.xhtml</welcome-file>`.

Comment: @Smutje. Already,I tried this <welcome-file>WEB-INF/welcomePage.xhtml</welcome-file> also but still in that same problem.

Comment: @Smutje if i set  <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/welcomePage.xhtml</welcome-file> then the welcomePage.xhtml is loaded but its produced an error like "java.lang.NullPointerException", I think the servlet container cannot translate the virtual path to a real path for any reason